# Importing module implicitly

Tags: python

In a directory, I have two files: `A.py`, and `B.py`. Here is their content:

```
# A.py

import numpy
x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
print x

# B.py

import A
y = numpy.array([4, 5, 6])
print y
```

From Command Prompt (Windows 8), I run the following command:

```
python A.py
```

which gives the output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

But when I run the following command:

```
python B.py
```

I get the output:

```
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

Why is this? Shouldn't numpy be imported implicitly into B via A?

Comment: No, why should it? After a module has been imported it's available in the namespace of that module, and only that module.

Comment: You need to use A.numpy

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
import A
```

That brings in all of the exportable functions and variables from the file `A.py` in, but with the namespace prefix of `A`

Assuming you don't want to do the import of numpy again in B (the normal option), your code then needs to be one of

```
import A
y = A.numpy.array([4, 5, 6])
```

Or:

```
from A import *
```

The former gets `numpy` via A, with the prefix of A (since that's where it was first imported), the latter explicitly imports all the things from A without a new prefix. The downside of the latter is it can bring in the rest of the kitchen sink too, so isn't generally a good plan for complex modules.

Normally though, if B needs numpy, it would import that directly. If A is making some changes to a module that it then exports, you would normally expect to import and reference it explicitly, to flag up to everyone looking at the code later that you're not dealing with the regular version of the library.

Comment: Downvote for *"Your code therefore needs to be one of..."* and listing two options that are.. uncommon to say the least, while missing the obvious solution: `B` needs `numpy`. Just import `numpy` in `B`.

Comment: Please don't do `from A import *` if you can ever help it!

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you put `import numpy` in B.py.

Currently your `import A` is redundant as you make no reference to it. Please read the tutorials first.